# Copy - Paste (iterating ) - Ms Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to writing codes in VB.

Can somebody help me in writing a VBA code to copy and paste data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 with certain conditions.

Sheet 1 : 
Column A B C data to be copied

Sheet 2 :

Copied data to be pasted in Column A alone in sheet 2

Final output be :

A1, B1, C1 data to be pasted in A1, A2, A3 
A2, B2, C2 data to be pasted in A4, A5, A6
And so on

And a condition be, after copy and pasting all data, remove all empty rows.

Comment: "Help me" suggests that you have some code already that does not exist.  It is generally recommended to post such - with details of how it fails, and what the expected result would be - as part of a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try this Macro
this macro copy data from sheet2 to sheet1
you can reverse it

```
 Option Explicit
    Sub Creasy_copy()
    Dim S1 As Worksheet, S2 As Worksheet
    Dim Ro%, Col%, i%, j%, m%
    Dim My_Rg As Range
    Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set S2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set My_Rg = S2.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    S1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    m = 1
  With My_Rg
    Ro = .Rows.Count
    Col = .Columns.Count
          For i = 1 To Ro
             For j = 1 To Col
                If .Cells(i, j) <> vbNullString Then
                  S1.Cells(m, 1) = .Cells(i, j)
                  m = m + 1
                End If
              Next
          Next
    End With
   End Sub
```